# Could not find com.android.support:design-23.2.1 and Could not find com.android.support.appcompat-v7-23.2.1 error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-appcompat

I can not compile an android project that is written in another computer.

The errors I get:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7-23.2.1:.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7-23.2.1//appcompat-v7-23.2.1-.pom
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7-23.2.1//appcompat-v7-23.2.1-.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7-23.2.1//appcompat-v7-23.2.1-.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7-23.2.1//appcompat-v7-23.2.1-.jar
         file:/C:/Users/umr/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7-23.2.1//appcompat-v7-23.2.1-.pom
         file:/C:/Users/umr/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7-23.2.1//appcompat-v7-23.2.1-.jar
         file:/C:/Users/umr/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7-23.2.1//appcompat-v7-23.2.1-.pom
         file:/C:/Users/umr/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7-23.2.1//appcompat-v7-23.2.1-.jar
     Required by:
         CalorieCalculator:app:unspecified
   > Could not find com.android.support:design-23.2.1:.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/design-23.2.1//design-23.2.1-.pom
         file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/design-23.2.1//design-23.2.1-.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design-23.2.1//design-23.2.1-.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design-23.2.1//design-23.2.1-.jar
         file:/C:/Users/umr/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design-23.2.1//design-23.2.1-.pom
         file:/C:/Users/umr/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design-23.2.1//design-23.2.1-.jar
         file:/C:/Users/umr/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design-23.2.1//design-23.2.1-.pom
         file:/C:/Users/umr/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design-23.2.1//design-23.2.1-.jar
```

Here is the build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7-23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design-23.2.1'
}
```

[sdkSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0k3Z.png)

Comment: Ensure that this computer has the "Android Repository" installed from the SDK Manager, and that it is up to date.

Comment: I checked it. It is enabled.

Comment: Can you please try to change the version numbers of the libraries from 23.2.1 to 23.1.1 in my case that was the problem.

Comment: What sdk location does your `local.properties` point to?

Answer (score 2):

There are some typos in your dependencies.

Change

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7-23.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design-23.2.1'
```

with

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to SDK Manager and go to SDK Tools tab. Check Android Support Library version and edit it in your build.gradle file. And if an error of "junit" comes, just remove that junit line from dependencies.

Comment: At the end of question there is a link called sdkSettings. If you check that image you can see that the support library's version is 23.2.1 and in the gradle file he is setting the version to 23.2.1 so it's the same...

Answer (score 0):

if you are importing other computer project on your android studio, make sure that project is compatible with your sdk, you are missing sdk support repository to compatible with that project,

so you have 2 way to run this project.

```
1. update sdk or,
2. create new project and copy paste module of that project with your sdk configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve it from the command line:

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --filter extra-android-m2repository --force --all
```

which basically installs **"Android Support Repository"** for the SDK Manager as [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) mentioned in the original question's comments.

**android** is a command that lives in `/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/tools/` for macOS or `[android sdk path]/android-sdk-linux/tools` for linux.